# Show that $((X_1,...,X_n)|X_1+\dots+X_n=t)$, $X_i \sim Exp(1)$ is uniformly distributed

Tags: uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

Let $X_i \sim Exp(1)$ be independent. I need to show that $((X_1,...,X_n)|X_1+\dots+X_n=t)$ is uniformly distributed over all nonnegative vectors that sum to t.

What does "over all nonnegative vectors that sum to t" mean?
What do I need to show exactly?

I assume I have to use the cumulutive distribution function and the indepence. Then I get
$$F_X(x) = F_{X_1}(x_1)\cdot ...\cdot F_{X_n}(x_n) = (1-e^{-x_1})\cdot...\cdot(1-e^{-x_n})$$

What do I have to do next?

Comment: Since $X_i\sim\Gamma(k=1,\,\theta=1)$, $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\sim\Gamma(k=n,\,\theta=1)$. You want to show the vector has [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) distribution with all $\alpha_i=1$.

Comment: Okay, so I have to show that the vector has the density $\Gamma (n)$. If I use the indepence I get $f_{(X_1,\dots, X_n)}(x) = e^{-x_1}\cdot ... \cdot e^{-x_n}$. So I have to show $e^{-x_1}\cdot ... \cdot e^{-x_n}= \Gamma(n)$? Where am I supposed to use $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i \sim \Gamma(k=n,\theta=1)$?

Comment: I've posted an answer that uses a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we weren't told $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i=t$, the joint PDF of the $X_i$ would be $\exp\left(-\sum_i x_i\right)$ on $[0,\,\infty)^n$. Over the $X_i\ge0$ region of the hyperplane plane $\sum_iX_i=t$ for some $t>0$, this PDF is $\exp(-t)$; and this region is a simplex of measure $\frac{t^n}{n!}$, so the probability density of $t$ is $\frac{t^n}{n!}\exp(-t)$ on $[0,\,\infty)$ (which, as a sanity check, indeed integrates to $1$). We obtain the conditional density of $\vec{X}$ by noting that, if $A$ is a subset of the above simplex,$$P(\vec{X}\in A|\sum_iX_i=t)=\frac{p(\vec{X}\in A)}{p(\sum_i X_i=t)},$$where the $p$ are probability densities. This is$$\frac{\int_A\exp\left(-\sum_ix_i\right)d^nx}{\frac{t^n}{n!}\exp(-t)}=\frac{\int_A\exp(-t)d^nx}{\frac{t^n}{n!}\exp(-t)}=\frac{n!}{t^n}\mu(A).$$Therefore, the density on an infinitesimal region in the hyperplane is $\frac{n!}{t^n}$.

Comment: Why is the probability density $p((X_1,\dots, X_n)\in A) = \int_A exp(-\sum_i x_i)d^nx$ ?

Comment: @Septime It isn't; a density won't be a probability. I said we obtained the density *by noting that* the conditional probability took a certain form for arbitrary $A$. Since the result is proportional to $\mu(A)$, the density itself is uniform.

Comment: But where does $\int_A exp(-\sum_i x_i)d^nx$ come from? What probability does it describe?

Comment: @Septime No, that integral is a density, because it's over a region of dimension $\le n-1$. I wrote a conditional probability as the ratio of two densities, in order to infer a third conditional density that integrates to that probability.

Comment: If it is a density but not $p((X_1,\dots,X_n)\in A)$. What density is it then? I'm sorry but I don't really understand the last part.

Comment: @Septime Although the integral is over $n$ variables, its integration range has a lower dimension, so we don't get a probability out of it. One way to think about it is that integrating over $t$ as well would achieve an integration over an $n$-dimensional region to get a probability, so on the fixed-$t$ subset $A$ the integral gives a $t$-density.